# How to supply raw_input to a python program running on a terminal window in linux from a different terminal, all running on same UNIX

Tags: python, linux, unix, terminal

I have 2 terminals open in a unix system.
On one terminal I have a python program running that accepts raw_input, and I want to supply this raw_input from the other terminal that is not running this python program.

I tried something like:

echo 3 > /dev/pts/172

But this is just printing the number 3 on the terminal but not really doing the function of giving "3" and ENTER key from keyboard

terminal 1 being /dev/pts/252 and terminal running python program being /dev/pts/172

Comment: Here is something to try.  Find the pid of the running python script using ps auxww|grep script_name or have the script print it out when it starts using os.getpid().  Stdin of the script should be available at /proc/script_PID/fd/0.  Redirect the output of the other terminal to this file with exec 1 > /proc/script_PID/fd/0. Now echo hello run in the other terminal will go to the input of the running script.  You could also run echo hello > /proc/script_PID/fd/0 in the other script but that requires adding '> /proc/script_PID/fd/0 ' to each line you want to input to the other script.

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to feed a program remotely, a fairly popular solution is not to use `stdin` for input, but to open a `pipe`, and have the program listen to the pipe. You can then open the pipe in another program, and send data to it. If you use [`named pipes`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node15.html), you can even `echo` to the pipe.

Sending data to `stdin` of another terminal (and, as such, to raw_input), is obviously a dangerous idea, as this would permit executing commands in someone else's terminal.

Directing to `/proc/script_PID/fd/0` won't work - this is linked to the same device in /dev/pts/.